# Update list one in response to entries in list two

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, flow

I have 2 lists. They both have Serial number as a column. 
list 1 is for jobs that need doing quarterly
list 2 is for the engineers to add the jobs as they do them. This list also includes jobs that may not be on the quarterly checks list.
i would like a way of list 1 updating the date completed by picking it up from list 2 IF the serial numbers match and it's marked as a scheduled job.

Should I try and use Flow? Calculated columns?
We are on SharepointOnline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using MS Flow. Based on your description i assume List 1 depends on List 2's info.

Start the flow when an item is created/modified in list 2 -> do your checks -> update list 1.

Calculated columns might work, but Flow gives you more freedom.

Comment: no list 1 doesn't depend on list 2, it just needs to update if a relevant change is made in list 2

Comment: Thats what i meant which is why you should start the Flow on list 2 and update list 1.

Comment: ahh ok... any pointers as to what the flow should like... I've got as far as a condition that checks the scheduled task yes/no toggle but after that i'm lost!

Comment: I'm a bit busy at work at the moment, i'll update my answer in a few hours, until then as an example -> If item is modified on list 2-> your checks -> Update Item (select List 1 and update what field you need, either use the built-in Update component or a RestAPI call inside Flow). Ref that you could read on this -> https://joannecklein.com/2018/02/19/microsoft-flow-update-sharepoint-columns/

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm struggling with the syntax of the comparison bit. equals(SerialNumber,@{triggerBody()?['SerialNumberofItem']}) doesn't work.

Comment: Sry i couldnt update my answer, broke my hand XD. What are you trying to compare? number fields?

Comment: oooh ouch. hope you're ok.

Comment: I need to compare the serial number entered in list 2 with the serial numbers already in list 1 and if a match is found the date in list 1 updated with the date from list 2

Comment: Sorted it. thanks for your help. I followed the instructions from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV3-lerjpus

Comment: Glad you found a way!